# naming conventions to differentiate a function (action) from a variable (option) in python

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Often I'll have little functions that do something. e.g. save_csv(), show_plot(), and then larger functions which do a bunch of stuff and optionally call the little functions. What's a decent naming convention for this to differentiate e.g. `save_csv()` as a function, and `save_csv` as a flag?
In C etc it's not unusual to use Hungarian notation and prefix the variables with a 'b' for 'boolean'. But I don't think that's very pythonic. And I've tried 'do_' prefix for the flag and it kind of works but is ugly and confusing too. I'm wondering if there's any conventions for this?

I couldn't see anything in pep8. 
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles

e.g.

```
def foo(..., b_resample, b_save_csv, b_save_plot, b_show_plot, b_compare):

    # do some stuff

    if b_resample:
        # do more stuff
        resample(...)

    if b_show_plot:
        # do more stuff
        show_plot(...)

    if b_compare:
        # do more stuff
        compare(...)

    # do more stuff

    if b_save_csv:
        # do more stuff
        save_csv(...)
```

UPDATE:
Bearing in mind that the arguments to the function are public facing, I'd like them to be 'decent' which is why I'm not a fan of hungarian notation  or leading underscores in this case. However I am considering switching to the below, where the public facing args are human readable, whereas internally they have leading underscores. Is this common practice?

```
def foo(..., **kwargs):
    _resample = kwargs.get('resample', False)
    _show_plot = kwargs.get('show_plot', False)
    _save_plot = kwargs.get('save_plot', True)
    _compare = kwargs.get('compare', True)
    _save_csv = kwargs.get('save_csv', True)

    # do some stuff

    if _resample:
        # do more stuff
        resample(...)

    if _show_plot:
        # do more stuff
        show_plot(...)

    if _compare:
        # do more stuff
        compare(...)

    # do more stuff

    if _save_csv:
        # do more stuff
        save_csv(...)
```

Comment: In Python, you usually go with a leading underscode `_save_csv` as you said.

Comment: I thought leading underscore was more to hint at private or internal use? e.g. internal functions etc often have leading underscore?

Comment: @memo that is correct. there is no convention for "minor" functions that I'm aware of, except possibly that they are exposed as part of the interface less often, so might have a leading underscore for that reason

Comment: I just updated my question with a proposition with leading underscores. I don't want public facing API to have leading underscores, but with kwargs it could work?

Comment: I’d suggest using `should_save_csv` for the flag, and plain `save_csv` for the function.

Answer (score 1):

Taken straight from [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names):

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

So I don't think there's a "pythonic" convention to differentiate a function from a variable that share the same name. I think it's more of a personal choice and as such, I'd personally use a variable called `has_save_csv` or `is_save_csv`(as Ramazan Polat has already mentioned).

**Update** Yes, it is a good practice to have variables starting with a leading underscore when you plan on using them internally. You can read more on this excellent [article](https://dbader.org/blog/meaning-of-underscores-in-python) that succinctly summarizes the meaning of underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, a boolean identifier should end with an adjective, so I would use a suffix like "wanted"; for instance *plot_wanted*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SaveCSV` for method name and `save_csv` for attribute name, although I don't recommend it. Because usually methods 'do' something for an object, while attributes are merely a state of an object.

In your case, I recommend you to use `save_csv()` for method name and `is_save_csv` as attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

Functions should be action verbs (like `run`, `check`, or `save`) describing what they DO. Whereas, variables should be words that describe what they ARE (so, usually nouns/adjectives, though some "passive" verbs are in this category like "has" or "needs")

In your example, `save_csv()` for the function and something like `has_save_csv` or `save_needed` as other users have suggested for the variable.